# Django formset save() writes new object on database?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

So I have MyModel:

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=80, unique=True)
    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if MyModel.objects.count() >= 5:
            raise ValidationError("Can not have more than 5 MyModels!")
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)  # Call the "real" save() method.
```

There are already 5 objects from MyModel on the database.
I have a page where I can edit them all at the same time with a formset.
When I change one or more of them, I will get the Validation Error "Can not have more than 5 MyModels!".
Why is this happenning? I tought the formset was supposed to edit the existing objects, but it appears to be writing a new one and deleting the old one.

What is really happening when I do a formset.save() on the database?
Do I have to remove the save() method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The save method inside the Model is called regardless you are creating or editing. Although you can distinguish between them by checking if the object has a primary key, like this:

```
if not self.pk and MyModel.objects.count() >= 5:
```

If you want more sophisticated control over validation, I suggest putting them [in the forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/validation/). Specially if you want to limit the number of formset, you can check this [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/formsets/#limiting-the-maximum-number-of-instantiated-forms).